# Modifying private object properties through method which returns reference

Tags: c++

I'm curious if that's proper way of assignement

```
class Foo { 
    int x_;

    public:
    int & x() {
        return x_;
    }
};
```

My teacher is making assignement like that: `obj.x() = 5;`
But IMO that's not the proper way of doing it, its not obvious and it would be better to use setter here. Is that violation of clear and clean code ? If we take rule that we should read the code like a book that code is bad, am I right ? Can anyone tell me if am I right ? :)

Comment: Can you elaborate more where you are creating obj object.
As per above class sample there is one basic problem you have kept every thing as private , so actually obj.x() will not work outside the class.
If you do not specify the access specifier it defaults to private

Comment: the is no "wrong" or "right" in general, but there are only millions of different ways of doing stuff, each behaving a bit different, if you want this behavior (i.e. exposing a reference to a private member) then its just fine. Look at e.g. `std::vector`, its `[]` or `at()` return a reference that lets you modify the values, there is nothing bad about that.

Comment: btw in your example both the variable and the method are private, which makes it a bit non sense....

Comment: @tobi303 sorry, method is public now

Comment: @tobi303 but when I'm returning the reference, I can pass it forward and make a mess in program, when there is a seter I'm not exposing this property to the world, it can be modified only by one method

Comment: IMHO this is lame, and setters are lame too. It's a matter of style really.

Comment: "...returning the reference, I can pass it forward.." ...sometimes thats exactly what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this code is not a good practice in terms of evolution. If you need to provide some changes checking, formatting, you have to refactor your class API which can become a problem with time.

1. Having `set_x()` would be a way cleaner. Moreover, it will allow you to have checking mechanics in your setter.
2. a proper getter `get_x()` or `x()` could also apply some logic (format, anything...) before returning. In your case, you should return `int` instead of `int&` since setter should be used for modification (no direct modification allowed).

And truly speaking, this code doesn't really make sense... it returns a reference on a property making it fully modifiable. Why not having directly a public property then ? And avoid creating an additional method ?

Do you want control or not on your data? If you think so, then you probably want a proper getter and setter. If not, you probably don't need a method, just make it public.

To conclude, I would say you are right, because the way you see it would make it better over the time, prone to non-breaking change, better to read.

As the UNIX philosophy mentions : "Rule of Clarity: Clarity is better than cleverness."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x()` happens to be `public` (or `protected`) member the function effectively exposes an implementation: the is an `int` held somewhere. Whether that is good or bad depends on context and as it stands there is very little context.

For example, if `x()` were actually spelled `operator[](Key key)` and part of a container class with subscript operator like `std::vector<T>` (in which case `Key` would really be `std::size_t`) or `std::map<Key, Value>` the use of returning a [non-`const`] reference is quite reasonable.

On the other hand, if the advice is to have such functions for essentially all members in a class, it is a rather bad idea as this access essentially allows uncontrolled access to the class's state. Having access functions for all members is generally and indication that there is no abstraction, too: having setters/getters for members tends to be an indication that the class is actually just an aggregate of values and a `struct` with all `public` members would likely serve the purpose as well, if not better. Actual abstractions where access to the data matters tend to expose an interface which is independent of its actual representation.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, the effect of returning a (non-const) reference is the same as if you made the variable public. Any encapsulation is broken. However, that is not a bad thing by default. A case where this can help a lot is when the variable is part of a complicated structure and you want to provide an easy interface to that variable. For example

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<std::list<std::pair<int,int>>> values;
    public: 
        int& getFirstAt(int i){
            return values[i].[0].first;
        }
};
```

Now you have an easy access to the first element of the first element at position `i` and dont need to write the full expression every time.

Or your class might use some container internally, but what container it is should be a private detail, then instead of exposing the full container, you could expose references to the elements:

```
class Bar {
    std::vector<int> values;   // vector is private!!
    public:
       int& at(int i){         // accessing elements is public
           return values.at(i);
       }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In general such a  code confuses readers.

```
obj.x() = 5;
```

However it is not rare to meet for example the following code

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 0 };
v.back() = 2;
```

It is a drawback of the C++ language.

In C# this drawback was avoided by introducing properties.

As for this particular example it would be better to use a getter and a setter.

For example

```
class Foo { 
    int x_;

    public:
    int get_value() const { return x_; }
    void set_value( int value ) { x_ = value; }
};
```

In this case the interface can be kept while the realization can be changed.